# cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined

Tags: html, json, forms, csv, cypress

I am trying to fill out an HTML form using a CSV file. For them I first convert the CSV file to JSON and then try to fill the form using the JSON file. However, the only thing I get is the error: cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined

I have checked the answers that have been given for this same problem but I can't find one that helps me. What am I doing wrong?

Here I leave the code with which I first pass the file from CSV to JSON, then it is logged in the console and finally I pass it through the form:

```
<!-- language: js -->
import {parse} from "papaparse"
    describe('Convert CSV file in JSON file', function(){
        let allData        
        before(()=>{
            cy.readFile('C:/data/cypress/downloads/generatedBy_react-csv.csv')
                .then(str =>{
                    cy.writeFile('C:/data/cypress/fixtures/testDataFromCSV.json', parse(str, {header:true}))
                })
            cy.fixture('testDataFromCSV.json')
                .as('dataJson')
                .then(dataJson => {
                    allData = dataJson
                })
        })
it('Log the data from the CSV to the JSON file', function(){       
    allData.data.forEach(data =>{
        cy.log(data.firstName)
        cy.log(data.lastName)
        cy.log(data.email)
        cy.log(data.age)
        cy.log(data.address)
        cy.log(data.vehicle)
        cy.log(data.phoneNo)
    })
})

it('Use JSON Data in hte HTML form', function(){       
    allData.data.forEach(data =>{
        cy.visit('http://localhost/2iTesting/form.html')
        cy.fixture("testDataFromCSV.json")
            .then((dataJson)=>{
                allData = JSON.stringify(dataJson)
                cy.get('[cy-data="firstname"]')
                    .type(data.firstName)
                cy.get('[cy-data="lastname"]')
                    .type(data.lastName)
                cy.get('[cy-data="email"]')
                    .type(data.email);
                cy.get('[cy-data="address"]')
                    .type(data.address);
                cy.get('[cy-data="vehicle"]')
                    .type(data.vehicle);
                cy.get('[cy-data="submit"]')
                    .click()
                cy.wait(1500)
            })
    })
})
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `stringify` step.

I think you intend to `parse`, but there's no need because Cypress already does it for you. Any file with `.json` extension is passed into the test as an object.

```js
cy.fixture("testDataFromCSV.json")
  .then((dataJson) => {

    // allData = JSON.stringify(dataJson)  // no need to do this, just use dataJson

    cy.get('[cy-data="firstname"]')
      .type(dataJson.firstName)    // NOTE you have data.firstName
    ...                            // which looks like a cut-and-paste error
                                   // from the test above
```

---

**Writing the data portion of the parse result**

The papaparse library gives you a wrapper object that contains the data, an errors array and meta data.

Ideally you want to check errors before writing the JSON, but at minimum you will need to write the `.data` property of the parse result.

```js
cy.readFile('./cypress/downloads/generatedBy_react-csv.csv').then(str =>{
  const result = parse(str, {header:true})
  if (result.errors.length) {
    // handle errors
  }
  cy.writeFile('./cypress/fixtures/testDataFromCSV.json', result.data)
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think that the problem is definetly in other place. When parsing from CSV file to JSON, the first row of the JSON file has strange symbols(  "?\"firstName\"": "Martin",...). So what I think is that when tryin to type(data.firstName), data.firstName is empty. I hope you understand me.

Comment: Indeed, I understand. The above code change is definitely needed, but first the JSON file needs to be correct. To debug, you will need to show the CSV and the `parse()` function.

Comment: Thanks @Fody for your quick reply. The parse() function is already in the code I posted. They are the first 10 lines or so. The CSV file is like: "firstName","lastName","email","address","vehicle"
"Martin","Barry","martinbarry@hotmail.com","123 Fake Lane, Fakeland, G12 3RE","Vauxhall Insignia"
"Elizabeth","Norman","elizabethnorman@googlemail.com","150, Inglewood Avenue, Bradford,BD45 3RE","Mercedes-Benz C Class Coupe"... and so on. And the JSON file generated is: {
  "data": [
    {
      "\"firstName\"": "Martin",
      "lastName": "Barry",
      "email": "martinbarry@hotmail.com"...

Comment: As you can see, in the JSON file there are symbols that should be there and I do not know where they are coming from. By the way, I'm using papaparse to parse the file

Comment: So, I've made a walk-around to solve this. The main problem was that the CSV file have some hidden characters  at the beginning of the header row. I tried to find a way to solve this problem, but it's something that has to be fixed in the data-generator app that I'm using (something related with UTF-8 encoding). The final and ugly solution has been to create a new field that won't be used in the form but will contain those characters.

Thank you very much because from your answer I've found other threads that end with this solution

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the scope of your then block. Inside the then block for this fixture. `cy.fixture('testDataFromCSV.json').as('dataJson').then(dataJson => { allData = dataJson})`

allData = dataJson

But outside the then block `alldata` = `let alldata` or just undefined. To get access to the assigned variable you need to use `cy.wrap()`.

```
cy.fixture('testDataFromCSV.json').as('dataJson')
.then( (dataJson) => {
  cy.wrap(dataJson).as(allData)
 }
```

To then access your wrapped object you simply do the following.

```
it('Log the data from the CSV to the JSON file', () =>{
cy.get('@allData')
.then( (allData) => {
  Object.Values(allData.data).forEach( (value) =>{ //this might be wrong as I'm unsure the data structure of your object
    cy.log(value)
  }
}
it('Use JSON Data in the HTML form', () =>{
cy.get('@allData')
  .then( (dataJson) =>{
    allData = JSON.stringify(dataJson)
    cy.get('[cy-data="firstname"]')
    .type(allData.data.firstName) //and so on from here
  }
```

One last thing to note, you have a `cy.wait(1500)` at the end of your second it block. I would suggest looking into `cy.intercept().as('api')` to catch whatever API response you are getting by clicking submit. Then its just a mater of `cy.wait('api')` which is a best practice.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think that the problem is definetly in other place. When parsing from CSV file to JSON, the first row of the JSON file has strange symbols(  "?\"firstName\"": "Martin",...). So what I think is that when tryin to type(data.firstName), data.firstName is empty. I hope you understand me.